# Shiny DT Highlight Cells if Value Appears in Another Set

Tags: r, shiny, set, highlighting, dt

### Issue:

I have a data frame where row A is the names of people in my organization. I have a separate data frame that is a subset of row A in the original table. I would like to highlight all rows in the first data table that match names in the second table. Essentially, I have two sets. Set A and Set B. Both are names, I would like to highlight the data table for all names in Set A that match Set B. However, I keep getting an error: `length(levels) must be equal to length(values)`

How would I avoid receiving this error?

### Reproducible Example:

I have a data frame of mtcars. I am filtering the mtcars dataset based on a slider input for mpg. I would like to highlight the data frame of mtcars that meet the filtering criteria. In effect, this would mean highlighting the output table for all observations where the mpg are <= the slider input mpg.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Highlight Cell Test (Sets)"),

   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel = 'side',
     sliderInput('slider', 'slider input', 1, 30, 20)),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         dataTableOutput("test")
      )
   )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


  subset <- reactive({
    mtcars %>%
      filter(mpg <= input$slider)
  })

  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable(
    mtcars %>%
      DT::datatable(
        options = list(
          dom = 'ftipr',
          searching = TRUE
        ) %>%
          formatStyle(
            'test',
            background = styleEqual(
              (subset()$mpg %in% mtcars$mpg), 'lightgreen'))
      )
  )

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via `rowCallback` like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
fnc <- JS('function(row, data, index, rowId) {','console.log(rowId)','if(rowId >= ONE && rowId < TWO) {','row.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen";','}','}')

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Highlight Cell Test (Sets)"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = 'side',
    sliderInput('slider', 'slider input', 1, 30, 16)),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("test")
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  subset <- reactive({
    mtcars %>% filter(mpg <= input$slider)
  })

  Coloring <- eventReactive(subset(),{
    a <- which(subset()$mpg %in% mtcars$mpg)
    print(a)
    if(length(a) <= 0){
      return()
    }
    fnc <- sub("ONE",a[1],fnc)
    fnc <- sub("TWO",max(a),fnc)
    fnc
  })


  output$test <- DT::renderDataTable(
    mtcars %>%
      DT::datatable(options = list(dom = 'ftipr',searching = TRUE,pageLength = 20, scrollY = "400px",rowCallback = Coloring()))
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you for this response. I was able to achieve the functionality I was looking for however I am getting some errors that I don't have enough an understanding of javascript to diagnose. So, it initially highlights the correct rows on the first page, but when click on next page, the same rows are highlighted and it doesn't actually highlight on the subsetted values. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Thats why I put down `scrollY = "400px"`. The example I provided will not work with paging